# 2nd echo statement in bash script not working

Tags: bash

For some reason I'm not getting the output of my 2nd echo line when I run my script. Here is my code snippet:

```
IS_RUNNING=$(netstat -anp | grep ":7600" | grep java | awk '{print   $7}' | cut -d"/" -f 2)

  start(){
  nohup /bin/su -c "/opt/app/bin/service start" - user  &>/dev/null &
  echo "Starting Services please wait"      
  sleep 30
  if [ "$IS_RUNNING" = java ];
  then
     echo "Service is now running"
     exit 0
  fi
}
```

Interestingly. when I run it with:

```
sh -x ./service start
```

I get the output expected and my 2nd echo gets written to the screen.

```
+ case "$1" in
+ start
+ echo 'Starting Services please wait'
Starting Services please wait
+ sleep 30
+ nohup /bin/su -c '/opt/app/bin/service start' - user
+ '[' java = java ']'
+ echo 'Service is now running'
Service is now running
+ exit 0
```

Without using sh -x, I simply get this:

```
[root@init.d]# ./service start
Starting Services please wait
[root@init.d]#
```

I have a feeling I'm overlooking something simple. Can anyone help?

Comment: Is it just me or is your `sh -x` output in a different order than the source you provided?

Comment: No, its copied right off the screen.

Comment: Can you rewrite this question to be more useful to other people? Someone else with a bash script where the second echo doesn't work almost certainly won't have the same underlying problem, and so answers to this aren't likely to be helpful to them.

Comment: I disagree. I think the question is fine and gets into enough specifics where it could be helpful. Walters answer below. resolved it for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The running line is evaluated once:

```
IS_RUNNING=$(netstat -anp | grep ":7600" | grep java | awk '{print   $7}' | cut -d"/" -f 2)
```

You should make a function for this or include this line in the start() function after the sleep.